# Jump to next semicolun

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions

I can use `fd` to jump to the next `d` character. How can I jump to the next semicolun? `f;` doesn't seem to work. Also, for other special symbols.

Thanks

Comment: It should work. Do you have a mapping overriding it? Check `:map f` and `:map f;`. If there's nothing there start vim with `vim -u NONE <file>` and try again. If that works than you have something in your configuration, probably a plugin, interfering with the default behavior.

Comment: There is something, not sure what it means. s f <SNR>92_yank_with_key("f")

Comment: That's a Select mode mapping. Are you seeing the problem in Normal mode or Select mode? If the former, what does `:nmap f` show? Regardless, I see a plugin called [vim-yankstack](https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/vim-yankstack) that has a similar looking mapping that is applied dynamically: `smap <expr>' key '<SID>yank_with_key("' . key . '")`. There is also a Normal mode mapping along the same lines. If you are using this plugin it seems like a good place to dig further.

Comment: Try `:echo g:yankstack_yank_keys`. If there's a result and it contains "f" (the default does not) then that's a probable cause.

Comment: the echo command answers with '[y','d']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while back. As a temporary solution you can use `/;`, and then use n.

This will search for `;` and jump to that position